# Which dropboxes can give Fennec bodies, if any?

Tags: rocket-league

I've heard conflicting opinions on whether a Fennec can be earned through a dropbox, so I'm asking here to find out. If it can, which dropbox rarity levels have a chance of giving them out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Fennec is ranked as **Import**, you can find one opening Rare, Very Rare or Import dropboxes, because every box has a chance to give a random item in the next 3 tiers.

- Rare box: Rare, Very Rare, **Import**
- Very Rare box: Very Rare, **Import**, Exotic
- Import box: **Import**, Exotic, Black Market

Which are these ones:

[image]